# What is the correct form to access to a memory address in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, att

Say I wanted to execute the line of code below , what would the result be?

`push -0x28(%ebp)`
I don't understand what address will be pushed

NOTE: Running on Intel x86

Comment: The value that will be pushed onto the stack is the same value as obtained into eax by the following simpler instruction: `mov eax,-0x28(%ebp)` (intel operand ordering not AT&T).  Note the difference between `mov` and `lea`: `lea eax,-0x28(%ebp)` -- this will compute %ebp-0x28 and load that directly into `eax` whereas the move will compute the same value but use it as the address to read from memory, which is then the result for eax.  The push is like the mov followed by push eax.

Comment: Since I can't change the code because I'm trying to reverse it, I was wondering what was the arithmetic behind the scenes the find the exact value of the address

Comment: Ok thank you @ErikEidt, is the same applying 0x28(%ebp) -- so the memory address will be %ebp+0x28?

Comment: yes address is value in %ebp plus 0x28

Comment: no, it is %ebp minus 0x28

Comment: @ErikEidt: Please don't mix Intel operand-order with AT&T addressing-mode syntax.  That takes extra mental effort for everyone to read, even if you do say what you're doing right afterwards.  In this case, writing `mov eax, [ebp - 0x28]` Intel-syntax addressing would had the side benefit of highlighting the minus.

Comment: @PeterCordes, sorry, my bad